# How to rank vertically in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I have a table in SQL in the following format

| ID | P1_Date | P2_Date | P3_Date | P4_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-30 | 2021-09-26 | 2021-09-24 | 2021-09-25 |
| 2 | 2021-08-20 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-07-24 | 2021-06-25 |
| 3 | 2021-08-20 | null | 2021-07-24 | 2021-06-25 |

Is it possible to rank it vertically and have results as below

| ID | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P3 P4 P2 P1 |
| 2 | P4 P3 P2 P1 |
| 3 | P4 P3 P1 |

Comment: simply, if it is null value then it is not included in rank?

Comment: @NitinS yes, the null value will be skipped

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: MySQL or Teradata? Those are two very different database products

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in MSSQL

```
DECLARE @colQuery NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @colQuery = '';
SELECT @colQuery = @colQuery + N'CASE WHEN '+ A.[Column] + N' IS NOT NULL THEN '''+  A.[Name] +' '' ELSE '''' END, '
FROM (
select
   syscolumns.name as [Column],
   REPLACE(syscolumns.name,'_Date','') as [Name]
from 
   sysobjects 
inner join 
   syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
where sysobjects.xtype = 'u'
and   sysobjects.name = 'TeraData'
and syscolumns.name like 'P%') A
GROUP BY A.[Column], a.[Name] 
order by A.[Column] desc, a.[Name] desc

SET @query = 'SELECT [ID], CONCAT('+substring(@colQuery, 1, (len(@colQuery) - 1))+') as Rank from TeraData';
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` to normalize the table so that you get 1 row for each `ID` and aggregate to get the result with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, P1_Date date, 1 n FROM tablename UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, P2_Date, 2 FROM tablename UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, P3_Date, 3 FROM tablename UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, P4_Date, 4 FROM tablename 
)
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT('P', n ORDER BY date SEPARATOR ' ') `Rank`
FROM cte
WHERE date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a70e8add2771cedf4b49b33a839344b).

Answer (score 1):

With a lateral join you can treat the columns as rows.
Then use group_concat to create a string.

> ```
> select *
> from your_table
> cross join lateral (
>   select group_concat(P_CODE order by p_date separator ' ') as `Rank`
>   from (
>     select 'P1' AS P_CODE, P1_DATE AS P_DATE 
>     union all select 'P2', P2_DATE
>     union all select 'P3', P3_DATE
>     union all select 'P4', P4_DATE
>   ) q
>   where p_date is not null
> ) p;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | P1_Date    | P2_Date    | P3_Date    | P4_Date    | Rank       
> -: | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :----------
>  1 | 2021-09-30 | 2021-09-26 | 2021-09-24 | 2021-09-25 | P3 P4 P2 P1
>  2 | 2021-08-20 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-07-24 | 2021-06-25 | P4 P3 P2 P1
>  3 | 2021-08-20 | null       | 2021-07-24 | 2021-06-25 | P4 P3 P1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5724439a451e0769224c0190fa1430b9)*

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata you can unpivot, rank & pivot like this:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT id, col, 
      Row_Number()
      Over(PARTITION BY id
           ORDER BY dt) AS rn
   FROM my_table
   UNPIVOT(dt FOR col IN(P1_Date AS 'P1'
                        ,P2_Date AS 'P2'
                        ,P3_Date AS 'P3'
                        ,P4_Date AS 'P4')) AS p
 )
SELECT pvt.*,
   Coalesce(r1, '') ||
   Coalesce(' ' || r2, '') ||
   Coalesce(' ' || r3, '') ||
   Coalesce(' ' || r4, '')   
FROM cte
PIVOT (Max (col) 
       FOR rn IN (1 AS r1
                 ,2 AS r2
                 ,3 AS r3
                 ,4 AS r4)
      ) AS pvt
```